# return a Mono<String> from FilePart (Java)

Tags: java, project-reactor

a class `UploadService` receives a `FilePart`, representing the content of the JSON below, from a REST API.

The target is to return a `Mono<String>` from this `FilePart` to build a `JSONObject`.

**This is the posted JSON:**

```
{
"machineId" : "7",
"printJobId" : "123",
"timeStampStartPrintJob" : "10:23:15,253",
"timeStampEndPrintJob" : "12:50:16,577",
"optionalMetadata" : {}
}
```

**This is my code:**

```
public class UploadService{

    public Mono<String> uploadSensorData(FilePart metaDataFile) {
        
        /*create + print a JSONObject*/
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(metaDataFileContentToString(metaDataFile).toString().trim().charAt(0));          
        System.out.println(result);

    }

    /*convert FilePart to String*/
    private Mono<String> metaDataFileContentToString(FilePart metaDataFile) {
        return metaDataFile.content()
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .collectList()
            .map(list -> String.join("", list));
    }

return null;

}
```

**Issue:** I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with my method `metaDataFileContentToString`. By now the output only shows the first and last curly bracket of the JSON: `{}`

Is there another way to get a proper `Mono<String>` from the bytes of the Filepart? Or is maybe the `.toString()` method by creating the JSONObject the problem?

Many thanks for your ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> The target is to return a `Mono<String>` from this FilePart to build a `JSONObject`

There's no need to do this - modern JSON libraries like Jackson have built in methods to asynchronously process a `Flux<DataBuffer>` straight into the type that's required, skipping the String.

So assuming you have a class `PrintJobInfo` that represents your data structure, you can just do something like:

```
Mono<PrintJobInfo> mono = new Jackson2JsonDecoder()
    .decodeToMono(fp.content(), ResolvableType.forClass(PrintJobInfo.class), null, null)
    .cast(PrintJobInfo.class);
```

In real-world use you'd probably want to expose your `Jackson2JsonDecoder` as a bean rather than creating a new one each time. Note it also has another constructor that can take an `ObjectMapper` if you need any custom configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What string do you want?

If you want a print of the json then use `ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString` or similar, or yes, `toString`.

To get a Mono then use `Mono::just`

However, you should not creat a `Mono` in your methods but rather you should be part of an existing `flow`. This means you should be getting a Mono and returning a Mono and your function is simply mapping the data from one type to another.

```
public Mono<String> uploadSensorData(Mono<FilePart> metaDataFile) {
    return metaDataFile.map(FilePart::toString);
}
```